# How to parse JSON data and print on vs code terminal in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

**This is my JSON data**

```
    {
            "id": 1072,
            "title": "Magnetism Doit Chapter 1",
            "gradeName": "Eight",
            "subjectName": "Science",
            "videoUrl": "hyRSO5RR3wo",
            "status": false,
            "createdDate": "2020-07-04 15:07:13",
            "admin": false
        },
```

I want to print only this data from json data in vs code terminal, How to get this data from whole JSON data ?

Comment: do your data return a list?

Answer (score 0):

If you will get your data from response, please make sure that your data converted with `jsonDecode()`

```
void main() {
  var mapData = [
    {
      "id": 1072,
      "title": "Magnetism Doit Chapter 1",
      "gradeName": "Eight",
      "subjectName": "Science",
      "videoUrl": "hyRSO5RR3wo",
      "status": false,
      "createdDate": "2020-07-04 15:07:13",
      "admin": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1072,
      "title": "Magnetism Doit Chapter 1",
      "gradeName": "Eight",
      "subjectName": "Science",
      "videoUrl": "hyRSO5RR3wo",
      "status": false,
      "createdDate": "2020-07-04 15:07:13",
      "admin": false
    },
  ];
  // json decode 
  // var data = jsonDecode(yourdata.body)
  
  // print data list
  mapData.map((element)=>print(ListItem.fromJson(element).title)).toList();
  
  // store data list
   List<ListItem> queryData =  mapData.map((element)=>ListItem.fromJson(element)).toList();
   print(queryData);
}

class ListItem{
  int id;
  String title;
  String gradeName;
  String subjectName;
  String videoUrl;
  bool status;
  String createdDate;
  bool admin;

  ListItem(
      {this.id,
      this.title,
      this.gradeName,
      this.subjectName,
      this.videoUrl,
      this.status,
      this.createdDate,
      this.admin});

  ListItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    gradeName = json['gradeName'];
    subjectName = json['subjectName'];
    videoUrl = json['videoUrl'];
    status = json['status'];
    createdDate = json['createdDate'];
    admin = json['admin'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['gradeName'] = this.gradeName;
    data['subjectName'] = this.subjectName;
    data['videoUrl'] = this.videoUrl;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['createdDate'] = this.createdDate;
    data['admin'] = this.admin;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i have this...but how to get response in vs code terminal by using print function

Comment: you try this code in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=08fdc9daa5b7bb540ac255c8074c2ace

Comment: @JahidulIslam updating your code to work with null safety which is showing up by default in dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=08fdc9daa5b7bb540ac255c8074c2ace